# Infinite list with context propagation

Tags: haskell

I want to build an infinite list, I tried using `Data.List.iterate`, but I need a context to be propagated (the context changes while propagated).

The `Data.List.iterate` is of type `(a -> a) -> a -> [a]`

I need something like `((a, context)->(a->context)) -> (a, context) -> [a]`

Until now I only obtained `[(a, context)]` and I can't do `map fst` because I will get something like `[1, 12, 123, 1234...]` instead of `[1, 2, 3, 4....]`.

Comment: Why `map fst` does not suit you? It precisely removes the context, and only that.

Comment: `fst` does but return pair's left element. If it does not return what you expected then your pair computation is wrong.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think `unfoldr` is exactly what you want:

```
Prelude> import Data.List(unfoldr)
Prelude Data.List> :t unfoldr
unfoldr :: (b -> Maybe (a, b)) -> b -> [a]
Prelude Data.List> let nrs = unfoldr (\n -> Just (n,n+1)) 1
Prelude Data.List> take 10 nrs
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

it works like this:

you have to give it a function which takes a state/context (the type `b` above) and either:

- returns `Just (output,newState)` if you want to go on
- return `Nothing` if you want to stop

so if you always return `Just ...` you get an infinite list of `[output]`s

Answer (score 3):

Update: I missed the `map fst` comment in the question, yet I can't see why it's not producing the expected result.

---

You can use `iterate` and discard the context later:

```
iter :: ((a, context)->(a, context)) -> (a, context) -> [a]
iter f x = map fst $ iterate f x
```

Laziness makes the `map` not to be applied further than necessary. Just make sure that `fst . f` is strict in the `context` argument, so that this does not build up large thunks.

It can also be used inline, since it's quite short:

```
> take 15 $ map fst $ iterate (\(a,b) -> (b,a+b)) (0,1)
[0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89,144,233,377]
```

Comment: based on the OPs last comment I think he knows this but he kind of wants the *very last* element (the fixpoint ;)) of this list

Comment: @Carsten Oh, I missed that... But I don't understand it.